# array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

Hello I have an Exercice where they give me this struct:

```
enum Sexe { INCONNUE=0, MASCULIN=1, FEMININ=2};

struct Personne {
    int numero;
    char nom[10];
    Sexe sexe;
};
```

And I need to make a pointer and assign values to it. So I did this function:

```
void Init() {
        Personne *p;
        string sexe;
        Sexe s;
        string n;
        string nom;
        char name[10];
        cout << "Choisissez le numero de la personne";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Choisissez le nom de la personne";
        cin >> nom;
        cout << "Choisissez le sexe de la personne";
        cin >> sexe;
        for (int i = 0; i < nom.length(); i++){
            name[i] = nom[i];
        }
        if (sexe == "1" || sexe == "Masculin" || sexe == "masculin" || sexe == "MASCULIN") {
            s = Sexe::MASCULIN;
        } else if (sexe == "1" || sexe == "Feminin" || sexe == "feminin" || sexe == "FEMININ") {
            s = Sexe::FEMININ;
        } else {
            s = Sexe::INCONNUE;
        }
        Personne join_p{stoi(n),name,s};
        p = &join_p;
}
```

But I have this error and I don't undestand why and how to fix it:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
         Personne join_p{stoi(n),name,s};
```

I tried to put the brackets at different places like they where saying in my lessons or other websites but it doesn't want to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this declaration

```
Personne join_p{stoi(n),name,s};
```

the data member of the structure `Personne` is declared like

```
char nom[10];
```

that is it is an array,

But the array `name` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

So you are trying to initialize an array with a pointer.

You may not initialize an array with a pointer. You need to copy the array `name` into the array `join_p.nom`.

Pay attention to that the array `name` does not contain a string but it seems that the data member `nom` must contain a string.

In any case this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < nom.length(); i++){
    name[i] = nom[i];
}
```

is unsafe because you can write outside the array `name`.

It would be better that initially the data member `nom` of the structure had the type `std::string`.

Also these statements

```
Personne join_p{stoi(n),name,s};
p = &join_p;
```

do not make a great sense because the pointer `p` is not used anywhere within or outside the function except this assignment.

Comment: How should I copy `name` into `join_p.nom`? I am sorry I am starting in c++.

Comment: @rob_runner Just declare the data member nom of the structure as having the type std::string . In this case you will be able to write Personne join_p{stoi(n), nom, s}; and the array name will be redundant.

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to change the struct

Comment: @rob_runner You need to append the array name with the terminating zero '\0' and then you can copy it in the data member nom using the standard C string function strcpy. But as I pointed your function in any case does not make a sense.

Comment: I just did like my exercice says : create a pointer to the struct then initialise all the variable on the pointer

Comment: @rob_runner It seems you need to allocate dynamically an object of the structure and then use a pointer to access data members of the structure to initialize theme.